# Partitioning a (string or integer) into n-elements of min (length or value) of 2

Tags: python, string, slice

I have a list of ~120'000 strings of various lengths (from 4 to 27) and I want to check if this strings are made of sub-strings that exist in a dictionary, and this sub-strings can be of various lengths and min 2 chars long.

For example a string 9 chars long would be divided into min 2 sub-strings. And of course I need all possible combinations

```
astring = '123456789'
# possible divisions
2 sub-strings = [['12','3456789'],['1234567','89'],['123','456789'],...]
3 sub-strings = [['12345', '67','89'],['1234','567','89']...]
4 sub-strings = [['12','34','56','789'],['12','34','567','89']...]
```

I found [code below at this address](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577665-partitioning-a-sequence/) and after rejecting results according to requirements I got what I need, but I'm not sure if it is not too slow. At 18 char long string, it takes 2 sec to process one string (hours for whole list). 
In case of 18 chars long string I get 1596 good slices out of 131072 possible, so 98% is useless.
Is there a faster way to do it ?

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def partition(iterable, chain=chain, map=map):
    s = iterable if hasattr(iterable, '__getslice__') else tuple(iterable)
    n = len(s)
    first, middle, last = [0], range(1, n), [n]
    getslice = s.__getslice__
    return [map(getslice, chain(first, div), chain(div, last))
            for i in range(n) for div in combinations(middle, i)]
some_string = '12345678'

for xyz in xrange(100):
    for x in partition(some_string):
        if (any(len(astring) == 1 for astring in x)):
            continue
        if len(x) == 1:
            continue
        # otherwise do something here
```

to specify in answer to **eyquem** comment:

I have a dictionary of words in Japanese (Japanese doesn't use spaces) and lots of words of length of 4 chars or longer are compound words made of shorter words. I want to filter out those words that can be split into shorter words. Later I could go through the list and make sure that slicing of words makes semantic sense.

This approach is kind of brutal force, which I thought would be simpler and I could use instead of more logical but more complicated for loop with limited recursion.
Starting from left and finding the longest possible word...

Regards
Bart

Comment: This might be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python

Comment: @tehjoker Code Review only reviews the author's own code.

Comment: How many sub-strings are concerned and to be searched among the 120'000 strings ? Why are these sub-stringspresent in a dictionary ? Are they keys or values in the dictionary, or inside collections being the dictionary's values ?

Comment: Python 2.7.11 documentation: ``operator.__getslice__(a, b, c) `` : Return the slice of a from index b to index c-1. **Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is removed in Python 3.x. Use getitem() with a slice index.**

Comment: Thx eyquem. In the mean time I wrote a code with limited recursion, and it works fast 0,7 sec for 70'000 entries but it took 80 lines, so definitely not elegant.
getslice(a, b, c) would be much better with generator  that partitions integers but skips results that contain 1 and that generates results from least number of integers to most.
I'm not sure if I should post the code here as it's not exactly answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this helps, but you could try implementing a modified [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).